# c# Cast generic List of enum

Tags: c#, list, enums, generic-programming

I have a list of enums that i filled, and for many reason i casted it to an object ob. A function receive this object and try to parse it as a generic Enum.

```
 List<MyEnum> mList = new List<MyEnum>();
  // i fill my list
  mList.Add(MyEnum.FirstValue);
  //...

  object ob = mList;
  if (ob.GetType().IsGenericType && ob.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
  {
    Type subTypeOb = ob.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.Single();
    if (subTypeOb.IsEnum)
    {
      foreach (Enum subOb in (List<Enum>)ob)
      {
        // do stuff
      }
    }
  }
```

The thing is, i want to cast it back to a generic List of Enum so that i can use it. I don't want and don't need to cast it back to it's original enum (it can be many other enum).

But i alwais get an error on: `(List<Enum>)ob`:

> can't cast object 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyEnum]' en type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Enum]'

I can't cast it to a List, i can't find a way to cast it in a list of anything generic.
What i don't understand is : between a generic Enum and MyEnum, there isn't a lot of difference, it's the same memory space.

Could you help me figure out?

---- EDIT --- More Infos
Oh  god i'm so stupid, i forgot to :`using System.Collections;`

Now i can do :   `List<Enum> enums = (ob as IList).Cast<Enum>().ToList();`

And it work perfectly fine ! Thanks you stranger.

Comment: you can cast `ob` to `IList` of course it will cause boxing

Comment: A list of `MyEnum` is not the same as a list of `System.Enum`. If your cast succeeded, then someone could add any `enum` to your list through the cast-ed reference. Generally, when I'm working with Reflection, I end up using the non-generic `IList` type: List<T> implements it, and it allows me to operate on the list as a list

Comment: C# does not allow generic type variance when it involves value types; so, yes, there is a big difference between `List<Enum>` and `List<myEnum>`, same as `List<int>` and `List<byte>`, etc. I don't see how you can avoid boxing in your specific scenario (`MyEnum` to `Enum` is a boxing conversión to begin with), so why don't you simple iterate an `IList`? What does strongly typing the list members to `Enum` help you with?

Comment: Flydog57 and InBetween had a good point, thanks, i am now looking at `IList` and how i can use it.

The things is, i'm filling an ihm based on the type of information i received, directly using `Enum` would help me parse every item of the list, just to make a `.GetType()` to later make an `Enum.getValues()`. (since `ob.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.Single()` already told me that they were enums)
(I understand the relative stupidity of making a `GetType()` on a `Enum`, but it's useful with an `object`, so i had hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading comments I think you are simpy looking for the extension method `Cast`:

```
var o = //some List<myEmum>;
List<Enum> enums = (o as IList).Cast<Enum>().ToList();

foreach (var e in enums)
{
    //whatever you need to do with e
}
```

And now you can iterate a `List<Enum>`. Of course, `Cast` is just a simple projection, you can do it manually inside your loop:

```
var listOfObjects = o as IList;
foreach (var o in listOfObjects)
{
    var e = (Enum)o;
    //whatever you need to do with e
}
```

In both cases you are incurring in boxing operations. `MyEnum` is a value type, and you are implictly casting (boxing) all members of the "untyped" list to object when interacting with the non generic `IList`. But, because you seem to want to actually use `Enum` typed members, and taking into account that `MyEnum` to `Enum` is already a boxing conversion, boxing per se doesn't seem to be an issue you are worryied about (or aware of).

Comment: I added more infos to my original post